# Shell: Is it possible to parse optional parameters after non-optional ones?

Tags: bash, optional-parameters

Lately I tried to to pass arguments in a shell script like this:

```
$./myscript.sh <sourcefile> <destinationfile> -o
```

The script should read in a sourcefile and a destinationfile - both should be mandatory - and then check additional optional parameters in the end. However when trying to parse the option `-o` with `getopts` - it never finds it. It's always "false" or "0". It only recognizes the option `-o`when it's passed before the other parameters!

```
$./myscript.sh -o <sourcefile> <destinationfile>
```

Is this mandatory that it only works this way? When I'm googling for rules, conventions or practise in scripts I never find these essential informations and only find it out through trial and error wasting a lot of time... Also I wonder how then a copy command process works, as it also mixes optional with non optional parameters

Comment: You could always capture and shift off the first 2 parameters before calling getopts.

Comment: That makes sense eventually. I tried to put them on the front previously but then forgot to shift them away before calling getopts. So it didn't work. Thanks man, I'm gonna try this out immediately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally in unix, optional parameters have come first, at least for most shell utilities, and that is the [Posix recommendation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) for writing shell utilities. The `bash` builtin `getopts` is designed for this use case as well; unless you yourself reorder the command line parameters, `getopts` will only work with option parameters coming first.

However, most gnu utilities use the gnu `getopt` or `getopt_long` C APIs, both of which by default allow optional parameters to come anywhere in the command line. And even with Posix shell utilities, there are some exceptions to the standard.

In short:

- you should always be safe putting optional parameters first, but in some cases you can put them at the end
- utilies written using the `bash` `getopts` built-in practically always require optional parameters to come first
- most Gnu utilities allow intermingled optional and positional parameters